# What are the pros and cons of using apache proxy_wstunnel module for handling websockets, compared to using a dedicated port and application for that?

Tags: php, apache, websocket

Hope anyone who is having an apache server and is going for WebSocket implementation would have to decide, whether they have to use port 80/443(apache) to handle WebSocket requests & connection, or to write a new application listening to a new port(like 8000).

What are the pros and cons of using apache proxy_wstunnel module, compared to using a dedicated port and application, for handling WebSockets? Is anyone holds advantage over the other?

Is there any implementation(preferably php) of WebSockets with apache proxy_wstunnel module?